# Checking inputs with knockout.js and php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm pretty new to knockout.js and I have the basics down but I'm confused on how to go about checking the inputs. I'm using PHP for grabbing POST information and knockout for creating the form.

I have a form that dynamically generates textboxes. Say I submit the form and one of the values doesn't pass the criterion. The form is now reset and everything is empty. With PHP I'd just set the value of the box = to what was posted, but since knockout uses the following syntax I'm not sure what to do with the posted values

Here's my javasctipt

```
//misc_form.js
function Form_Entry(name) {
   var self = this;
   self.name = ko.observableArray([]);
}

function EntriesViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.entries = ko.observableArray();

    self.add_entry = function() { 
        if(self.entries().length < 3){
        self.entries.push(new Form_Entry( ));
        }
    }
    self.remove_entry = function(name) { self.entries.remove(name) }

}
ko.applyBindings(new EntriesViewModel());
```

And the HTML

```
<table>
    <thead><tr>
    <th>Field Name</th><th></th>
    </tr></thead>
    <form method="post">
         <tr><td>Form Name</td><td><input type="textbox" name="form_name"/></td></tr>
         <tbody data-bind="foreach: entries">
         <tr>
         <td>Label</td><td><input data-bind="value: name"/></td>
         <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.remove_entry">Remove</a></td>
        </tr>    
    </tbody>
</table>
<button data-bind="click: add_entry">Add Input Textbox</button>

    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="hidden" name="entries" data-bind="value: ko.toJSON(entries)" />
    <button type="submit">Submit Form</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post the form via `$.ajax` and pass back any values that don't validate (as JSON perhaps) then  just set the values of the observables you have bound to the text box to those passed back from validation to show the user.

There are many ways to do it, something along these lines:

JS:

```
//in view model
var self = this;
this.textBox1 = ko.observable();
//...

//validate
$.ajax({
  url: 'validateForm.php',
  success: function(data) {
    if (data.success === false) {
         //set value of textbox back to old value
         self.textBox1(data.textBox1);
         //and so on...
    }
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<input data-bind="value: textBox1" />
```

PHP:

```
//validate...
//....
$returnData = array('success' => FALSE, 'textBox1' => $textBox1Val);
echo json_encode($returnData);
```

---

UPDATE:  Following your updated code I created a jsFiddle with updates to your code.  Knockout expects correct markup to work correctly (your `<table>` and `<form>` nesting) and I have added example code on how to make the submit button call a JS function.

You can see the code here:  http://jsfiddle.net/3sduY/1/

Comment: I updated my code above to show what I have. I tried to bind the submit button to a function but it didn't work. Can you please provide some tips?